# cleaning up unused locks in a NamedReaderWriterLocker

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, locking

For doing asynchronous file IO I have made a class that lets me lock based upon a string key to prevent doing multiple writes at the same time to the same file or prevent having both writes and reads be done at the same time. The problem I face however is that its possible to grow the _lockDict by sending a different key each time. The old unused locks are not cleaned up but I do not know how I could do this in a threadsafe manner. This could potentially lead to a very big memory consumption.

The class that gives back a instance of a lock based upon a key:

```
    public class AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker
{
    private readonly object _mutex = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, AsyncReaderWriterLock> _lockDict = new Dictionary<string, AsyncReaderWriterLock>();

    public Task<IDisposable> EnterReaderLockAsync(string name)
    {
        var locker = GetLock(name);
        return locker.EnterReaderLockAsync();
    }

    public Task<IDisposable> EnterWriterLockAsync(string name)
    {
        var locker = GetLock(name);
        return locker.EnterWriterLockAsync();
    }

    private AsyncReaderWriterLock GetLock(string name)
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (!_lockDict.TryGetValue(name, out AsyncReaderWriterLock locker))
            {
                locker = new AsyncReaderWriterLock();
                _lockDict.Add(name, locker);
            }
            return locker;
        }
    }
```

And the lock itself (idea from: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock/):

```
   public class AsyncReaderWriterLock
{
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>> _writerQueue = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>>();
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>> _readerQueue = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>>();
    private readonly WriterLocker _writerLocker;
    private readonly ReaderLocker _readerLocker;
    private readonly object _mutex = new object();
    private int _locksHeld;

    public AsyncReaderWriterLock()
    {
        _writerLocker = new WriterLocker(this);
        _readerLocker = new ReaderLocker(this);
    }

    public Task<IDisposable> EnterReaderLockAsync()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (_locksHeld >= 0 && _writerQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                _locksHeld++;
                return Task.FromResult<IDisposable>(_readerLocker);
            }
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>();
            _readerQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    public Task<IDisposable> EnterWriterLockAsync()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (_locksHeld == 0)
            {
                _locksHeld = -1;
                return Task.FromResult<IDisposable>(_writerLocker);
            }
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>();
            _writerQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseLocks()
    {
        if (_locksHeld != 0)
            return;

        // Give priority to writers.
        if (_writerQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            _locksHeld = -1;
            var tcs = _writerQueue.Dequeue();
            tcs.TrySetResult(_writerLocker);
            return;
        }

        // Then to readers.
        while (_readerQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            var tcs = _readerQueue.Dequeue();
            tcs.TrySetResult(_readerLocker);
            ++_locksHeld;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseReaderLock()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            _locksHeld--;
            ReleaseLocks();
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseWriterLock()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            _locksHeld = 0;
            ReleaseLocks();
        }
    }

    private class ReaderLocker : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AsyncReaderWriterLock _asyncReaderWriterLock;

        internal ReaderLocker(AsyncReaderWriterLock asyncReaderWriterLock)
        {
            _asyncReaderWriterLock = asyncReaderWriterLock;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _asyncReaderWriterLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }

    private class WriterLocker : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AsyncReaderWriterLock _asyncReaderWriterLock;

        internal WriterLocker(AsyncReaderWriterLock asyncReaderWriterLock)
        {
            _asyncReaderWriterLock = asyncReaderWriterLock;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _asyncReaderWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Example of using the AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker class:

```
    public class AsyncFileIO
{
    private static readonly AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker = new AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker();

    public async Task CreateFile(string filename, byte[] data)
    {
        using (await AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker.EnterWriterLockAsync(filename))
        {
            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }
            using (var stream = File.Create(filename))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        using (await AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker.EnterReaderLockAsync(filename))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filename)) return null;
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                var data = new byte[stream.Length];
                await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 0);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task DeleteFile(string filename)
    {
        using (await AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker.EnterWriterLockAsync(filename))
        {
            var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryName)) return;
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Note iam mostly interested in this for learning purposes and fully realize that this is overkill for most applications.

Comment: You'll need to add a way to mark a lock as unused. That would likely be done in whatever client is handing out the file names. Once that decides a filename is no longer needed it can tell your `AsyncNamedReaderWriterLocker` to dump the lock. That being said, that same actor could just as easily coordinate who reads and writes what file such that you do not need concurrent file access. To get anything more specific it would be helpful to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, also why you need concurrent file access as opposed to asynchronous access as stated?

Comment: With doing things asynchronous also comes concurrency. You could try to read and write to the same file at the same time causing concurrency. This is why the lock is needed to prevent writing and reading to the same file at the same time. This code will be used in a server to serve files and some additional logic such as generating thumbnails of images. What I am looking for is that the lock will be cleaned up once it's no longer used (in a threads are way).

Comment: you will have to keep track of how many threads are holding or waiting on the lock (your lock appears to have this information already), and then when a lock is released, if there are no other threads waiting, remove the lock from your dictionary. Of course, this will require additional synchronization at the release step, to ensure that no thread has retrieved the lock from the dictionary while you're in the process of releasing it. I am skeptical that this is better than just using one lock for all resources (especially given the likelihood of all I/O operations bottlenecking at the disk).

Answer (score 0):

At first I was running into deadlocks when trying to synchronize the async named lock in order to remove the unused locks. This was because not all locks were released in the same order. Fixing this needed a specialized AsyncReaderWriter lock just for use with this async named lock. It now looks like this:

```
    public class NamedAsyncReaderWriterLockController<TKey>
{
    private readonly object _mutex = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock> _lockDict = new Dictionary<TKey, NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock>();


    public Task<IDisposable> EnterReaderLockAsync(TKey name)
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            var locker = GetLock(name);
            return locker.EnterReaderLockAsync();
        }
    }

    public Task<IDisposable> EnterWriterLockAsync(TKey name)
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            var locker = GetLock(name);
            return locker.EnterWriterLockAsync();
        }
    }

    private NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock GetLock(TKey name)
    {
        NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock locker;
        if (!_lockDict.TryGetValue(name, out locker))
        {
            locker = new NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock(this, name, _mutex);
            _lockDict.Add(name, locker);
        }
        return locker;
    }

    private void RemoveLock(TKey name)
    {
        _lockDict.Remove(name);
    }

    private class NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock
    {
        private readonly TKey _name;
        private readonly NamedAsyncReaderWriterLockController<TKey> _namedAsyncReaderWriterLockController;
        private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>> _writerQueue = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>>();
        private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>> _readerQueue = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>>();
        private readonly NamedWriterLock _namedWriterLock;
        private readonly NamedReaderLock _namedReaderLock;
        private readonly object _mutex = new object();
        private readonly object _releaseMutex;
        private int _locksHeld;

        public NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock(NamedAsyncReaderWriterLockController<TKey> namedAsyncReaderWriterLockController, TKey name, object releaseMutex)
        {
            _namedWriterLock = new NamedWriterLock(this);
            _namedReaderLock = new NamedReaderLock(this);
            _releaseMutex = releaseMutex;
            _name = name;
            _namedAsyncReaderWriterLockController = namedAsyncReaderWriterLockController;
        }

        public Task<IDisposable> EnterReaderLockAsync()
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (_locksHeld >= 0 && _writerQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    _locksHeld++;
                    return Task.FromResult<IDisposable>(_namedReaderLock);
                }
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>();
                _readerQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }

        public Task<IDisposable> EnterWriterLockAsync()
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (_locksHeld == 0)
                {
                    _locksHeld = -1;
                    return Task.FromResult<IDisposable>(_namedWriterLock);
                }
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IDisposable>();
                _writerQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }

        private void ReleaseLocks()
        {
            if (_locksHeld != 0)
                return;

            // Give priority to writers.
            if (_writerQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                _locksHeld = -1;
                var tcs = _writerQueue.Dequeue();
                tcs.TrySetResult(_namedWriterLock);
                return;
            }

            // Then to readers.
            while (_readerQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                var tcs = _readerQueue.Dequeue();
                tcs.TrySetResult(_namedReaderLock);
                ++_locksHeld;
            }

            if (_locksHeld == 0) _namedAsyncReaderWriterLockController.RemoveLock(_name);
        }

        private void ReleaseReaderLock()
        {
            lock (_releaseMutex)
            {
                lock (_mutex)
                {
                    _locksHeld--;
                    ReleaseLocks();
                }
            }
        }

        private void ReleaseWriterLock()
        {
            lock (_releaseMutex)
            {
                lock (_mutex)
                {
                    _locksHeld = 0;
                    ReleaseLocks();
                }
            }
        }

        private class NamedReaderLock : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock;

            internal NamedReaderLock(NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock namedAsyncReaderWriterLock)
            {
                _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock = namedAsyncReaderWriterLock;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }

        private class NamedWriterLock : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock;

            internal NamedWriterLock(NamedAsyncReaderWriterLock namedAsyncReaderWriterLock)
            {
                _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock = namedAsyncReaderWriterLock;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _namedAsyncReaderWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
            }
        }
    }
```